# Unable to post chatter - first message

Tags: chatter

On my org, I can post a chatter message as long as it had been posted before.
This below image, there was several messages before, so I can click on Comment or write a comment...

[image]

But in here, since there is no previous messages, there is no field for me to write anything or button to post. How do I post?

[image]

Edit page screenshot, Im adding the Chatter, not Chatter Feed:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the Post and/or Poll Lightning Actions in the page layout in order to share/post a chatter.

1. Go to the respective object layout
2. Click into Mobile & Lightning Actions
3. Drag Post & Poll actions over to the **Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions** section
4. Hit Save

Comment: Indeed, it was missing the global action. This solved the issue thanks!!